# How to extract Json data and get all the values in java?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to display all values from the below Json,but by using the below code i can only 
able to show one loop value at a time.

say if it is the key, "Name"

I am getting like this in my console

```
##-- NAME  :   abcd
```

but i need to show all data which are all belongs to the keys "**Name**" and "**E_ID**"

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks for your precious time!..

**sample.java**

```
 String strjson = "[\n    {\n        \"SampleList\": [\n            {\n                \"Name\": \"abcd\",\n                \"E_ID\": \"123\"\n            }\n        ]\n    },\n    {\n        \"SampleList\": [\n            {\n                \"Name\": \"efgh\",\n                \"E_ID\": \"456\"\n            }\n        ]\n    }\n]";



JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(strjson);
for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) 
                {

                    String str_alldata = jarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("SampleList");

                    JSONArray newjarr = new JSONArray(str_alldata);

                    for (int j = 0; j < jarr.length(); j++)
                    {

                        String name = newjarr.getJSONObject(j).getString("Name");
                        String id   = newjarr.getJSONObject(j).getString("E_ID");

                        System.out.println(">>-- NAME  :   "+name);                        
                        System.out.println(">>-- E_ID  :   "+id);                        

                    }


                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal loop is using the length of the wrong array, try using

```
 JSONArray newjarr = new JSONArray(str_alldata);

for (int j = 0; j < newjarr.length(); j++)
{
```